# figures tables and listings. Need an equal vspace above them all

Tags: tables, floats, listings, environments

I have a document in which are several figures, tables and listings.

Is there any way to define an uniform spacing for all environments, especially the vspace after the text before the figure/table/listing begins?
Can i wrap it anyhow into global settings?

So far i used `\vspace{10pt}` before the figure, table, listing starts but I don't want to write it in front of every fig/tab/lst.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]%
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
        hello & test & ok \\\hline
        its & a long text & for this table \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{i am the caption for this table} 
\end{table}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This text should show what a
printed text will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information? Is there a difference between this

\begin{lstlisting}
  public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("test");
      //test
    }
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{kaefer.png}}
  \caption{example of a beetle}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

I want to increase the green frames in the picture by 10pt. I used vspace{10pt} before. but it seems kind of wrong to do it like this `:/`.

[image]

Comment: you should never use `\vspace` before a float such as a `figure` or `table` environment as if the float _floats_ (ie is moved to another page) the vspace will make a spurious unwanted space at the original position. But without any example it is hard to guess what you are doing or how to change it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The space around `here` floats that appear mid page is `\intextsep` so you can put

```
\setlength\intextsep{...}
```

to whatever value you need in the document preamble.

You could put the listing in a `listings` float in which case it would have the same spacing and a caption etc. or you could use the aboveskip and belowskip keys for lstlistings

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setlength\intextsep{1cm plus .5cm minus.2cm}
\begin{document}
\blindtext

\begin{table}[htb]%
  \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}\hline
        hello & test & ok \\\hline
        its & a long text & for this table \\\hline
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{i am the caption for this table} 
\end{table}

Hello, here is some text without a meaning. This text should show what a
printed text will look like at this place. If you read this text, you will get no information. Really? Is there no information? Is there a difference between this

\begin{lstlisting}[float=htp]
  public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println("test");
      //test
    }
  }
\end{lstlisting}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \fbox{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image.png}}
  \caption{example of a beetle}
\end{figure}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: so is it correct, that when I set `intextsep{1cm plus .5cm minus .2cm}` this applies to the top and the bottom space? So in total 2cm?  Because when I use your suggested `aboveskip` and `belowskip` I have to add 1cm for above and 1cm for below to get the same results as in intextsep.

Comment: @dokukaefer yes

Answer (score 1):

After loading the `etoolbox` package, you can control the space before different environments like this:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox

\def\spabove{12pt}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{figure}{\kern \spabove}%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{table}{\kern \spabove}%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\kern \spabove}%
```

**Edit**

Possible issues can arise from using `kern` as pointed out by @DavidCarlisle, so one can make use of `\addvspace{x\baselineskip}`.

```
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{figure}{\addvspace{2\baselineskip}}%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{table}{\addvspace{2\baselineskip}}%
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{lstlisting}{\addvspace{2\baselineskip}}%
```

Comment: That's probably not a good idea kerns will not merge well with the existing space and you probably want different space depending on whether the float is finally positioned at top of page, bottom of page or mid-page. (`t`, `b` or `h`)

Comment: This is still wrong it is equivalent to doing `\addvspace{2\baselineskip}\begin{figure}....\end{figure}\addvspace{..}` so it will add 2\baselineskip (twice) at the point the figure is entered even if it is typeset on the next page, or the end of the document.